# Get object's attribute into java for each loop

Tags: java

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age= age; 
    }
    Person Rome[] = new Person[10];

    public void initializes {
        Rome[0]= new Person ("Antonio",20);
        Rome[1]= new Person ("Marco",11);
        //...
        Rome[9]= new Person("Giuseppe",27);
    }
    public void printName(){
        for(Person x : Rome){
            System.out.println(x.name);
        }
    }
    //TEST CLASS
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Person obj = new Person();
        obj.initializes();
        obj.printName(); // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    }
}
```

why the print of for each work just with primitive object , if i want print a attribute of complex object not work why?

Comment: `Rome[0]` is `null`. You need to initialize it.

Comment: no, because in the test i call obj.initializes();
array Rome is ok there are all object Person...

Comment: Have you tried rerunning your code now that you've edited it to initialize `Rome[0]`? If you still have an NPE, post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `Rome[0]` object.
It will be look like:

```
public void initializes {
    Rome[0]= new Person ("name",00);
    Rome[1]= new Person ("Antonio",20);
    //...
}
```

And code will be better if you'll initialize your object without object class. In test class for example:

```
Person[] Romeo = new Person[] {
 new Person(name, 00),
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the result:

the file name `Test.java`
//and there is the code. it is prototype and I did'n compile it, but it is an example for you

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age= age; 
    }

    public void printName(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
//Test class
public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Person[] Romeo = new Person[] {
           new Person("name", 00),
           //...
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//or another loop style
           Romeo[i].printName();  
    }
}
```